# chromium: change scrollbar color

Tags: chrome, browser

Is it possible to change color of the scrollbar in Chromium browser, without having to install yet another extension?

Perhaps by modifying some css file somewhere?

I am using chromium 83 on Debian 10.

I know how to achieve this in Firefox. I just added following lines to `userContent.css`

```
html,body{
    scrollbar-color: #B63C29 #555555 !important;
}
```

Is there something similar I can do to achieve same for Chromium?

## UPDATE:

I have tried following solution, but it has no effect:

1. I have created directory `~/.config/chromium/Default/User StyleSheets/`
2. created file `Custom.css` inside it
3. added following code to test it:

```
    .scrollable-element {
      scrollbar-color: red yellow;
    }
```

Nothing.
No effect.

Can somebody please show me simple **working** example how to change the scrollbar to red?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If nothing else works you may need to use some kind of extension after all.
Based on [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=340072) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948850/google-chrome-custom-css-webkit-scrollbar-no-longer-works/21999666#21999666) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948850/google-chrome-custom-css-webkit-scrollbar-no-longer-works/23271515#23271515) I did that:

```
$ mkdir CustomCSS && cd CustomCSS
$ cat > manifest.json << EOF
 
{
    "name": "My Style Sheet",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["*://*/*"],
          "css": ["Custom.css"]
        }
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "User StyleSheet replacement",
    "manifest_version": 2
}
EOF
```

```
$ cat > Custom.css << EOF
 
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    background: yellow;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: red;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1ex;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background: #000;
}
EOF
```

In `chrome://extensions` with developer mode on: Load unpacked extension -> choose path/to/CustomCSS

And that's it. It works. Red scroll bar on yellow background.

Checking  `chrome://memory` reveals it uses ~1.8MiB of memory.

--

Ed:
If you want to override websites' styles you may try to use [`!important` rule](https://www.w3schools.com/css//css_important.asp)

```
background: red !important;
```

Comment: - thank you. after loading the extension, the scrollbar changes shape, from square corners to round, but I only see my custom color on few websites. Others seem to override the color.

Comment: installing this as extension worked, but there is one small problem: This "extension" now appears as icon in the "extension pane" in the top right corner. I really don't want yet another useless icon there. Is there any way to hide it?

Comment: My chrome is old and doesn't have such stuff, so I don't know what to tell you. In Firefox there is easy option to customize menu, maybe there is something like that in chrome.

Comment: It's strange as the extension doesn't do anything with menu explicitly.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is possible.

[!ddg chromium scrollbar color](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=chromium+scrollbar+color&ia=qa)

[How can I change the scroll bar in Google Chrome to have different colors?](https://superuser.com/questions/852298/how-can-i-change-the-scroll-bar-in-google-chrome-to-have-different-colors)

[How to change the scrollbar style and color in Chrome](https://dottech.org/162855/how-to-change-the-scrollbar-style-and-color-in-chrome-tip/)

[Style the scrollbar with css in Google Chrome (-webkit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664325/style-the-scrollbar-with-css-in-google-chrome-webkit)

And yet another one found following above links:

> Google Chrome or Chromium

> Google Chrome provides a user stylesheet that you can modify in the configuration folder or the user profile folder. In Chromium/Linux, it is located at ~/.config/chromium/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css. For Google Chrome it is at ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/User StyleSheets/. In MS Windows, the location is %AppData%\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets.
> Depending on the browser version and OS this could vary but check the configuration folder on your system under the folder /Default/User StyleSheets/. Also If there is no file named Custom.css then you will need to create one inside the folder User StyleSheets/.

[how to use a custom or user stylesheet (css) in a web browser](https://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/using-a-custom-stylesheet-in-a-web-browser/).

Comment: I don't understand why I get negatives. This question has been answered on other sites but can not be flagged as duplicate because they're not unix.SE.

Comment: none of these links answer my question

Comment: Yes, they do. You need to read them. And formally, I have answered your question in one, simple sentence.

Comment: I have created directory `~/.config/chromium/Default/User StyleSheets/` and inside created file `Custom.css`. Added `.scrollable-element {   scrollbar-color: red yellow; }`, but no effect. Are you sure this should work? The answers provided all seem to require installing some kind of extension.

Comment: I have updated my question, and started a bounty. Thanks.

Comment: I checked paths and *chrome* (not *chromium*) uses `~/.config/google-chrome/` or `~/.google-chrome/`  instead of `~/.config/chromium/` for settings so you may need to check those paths as well. Theoretically you can check it at [chrome://version](chrome://version) but for me, for example, it keeps some settings at *~/.config/google-chrome/* when *chrome://version* says it's *~/.google-chrome/*.

Comment: Also, it may not work though as apparently chromium [removed the concept of user stylesheets](https://codereview.chromium.org/66383005/) some time ago, which I didn't know till now. Although there was an effort to reintroduce it, it [doesn't seem to work](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=347016) as expected.
So you might need to use some kind of extension. I read about such uncompressed extension but lost a sight of site.